# Centering is not working

Tags: horizontal-alignment

The below piece of code is not getting center aligned. Kindly help in finding out the solution for the same

```
\begin{table}[!ht]
\begin{tabular}{|c||c|c|c|c|c|} \hline
\centering
AE mode & 512 Byte & 1KB  & 1 MB & 1 GB & 2048 PetaBytes ($2^{64}$) \\ \hline \hline
%IACBC & BC & & & m + 2 & n & n & n & 2 independent random keys are required  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
```

Comment: You want to center the `tabular` itself. Then you should put `\centering` outside that environment (but still inside `table` environment). By the way, don't you have an extra `}`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) In the future, please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That way, it'll be much easier for other users to see your problem.

Comment: @Manuel You should make than an answer

Answer (score 3):

You want to center the `tabular` itself. Then you should put `\centering` outside that environment (but still inside `table` environment). By the way, you have an extra `}`.

```
\begin{table}[!ht]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|c||c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    AE mode & 512 Byte & 1KB  & 1 MB & 1 GB & 2048 PetaBytes ($2^{64}$) \\ 
    \hline
    \hline
    %IACBC & BC & & & m + 2 & n & n & n & 2 independent random keys are required  \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```