# Centering is not working in a minipage

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment

I've seen this answer: [Centering is not working](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155455/centering-is-not-working), but my problem is not centering a tabular environment.

I want to center the second line in a two line minipage.

- The contents of the minipage are given by a definition.
- The text is a constant width, hence the need for a minipage.
- The definition is needed because the text changes through iterations.
- The `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` environment is not desirable because of the added vertical space.
- `align=left` as an argument on `\node` is necessary to left align the first line.  However, removing this does not change the alignment of either line in the definition.

Where I'm now putting `\centering` in not achieving the desired result.

How can I get the second line centered while left-aligning the first line, given the current constraints/conditions?

I'm working with the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.0cm, y=1.0cm] 

    \node[circle, draw=red] (aa) at (0,0) {};               
    \def\myreference{References: \\ {\centering Kim, et. al., May 2019 } }
    \node[align=left, draw=black,
                  xscale=1.0, yscale=1.0, 
                  rounded corners=1.5ex,
                  inner xsep=0.150cm,
                  above = 0.00cm of aa
                  ] (reference) {\begin{minipage}{0.50\textwidth} \setstretch{0.5} { \tiny \myreference }\end{minipage} };


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're almost there; you just need to add `\raggedright` and `\\`.

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.0cm, y=1.0cm] 
\node[circle, draw=red] (aa) at (0,0) {};               
\def\myreference{References: \\ {\centering Kim, et. al., May 2019 \\ } }
\node[
  align=left,
  draw=black,
  xscale=1.0,
  yscale=1.0, 
  rounded corners=1.5ex,
  inner xsep=0.150cm,
  above = 0.00cm of aa,
] (reference) {%
    \begin{minipage}{0.50\textwidth}
    \setstretch{0.5}\tiny\raggedright
    \myreference
    \end{minipage}%
 };


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.0cm, y=1.0cm] 

    \node[circle, draw=red] (aa) at (0,0) {};               
    \def\myreference{References: \\\hfill Kim, et. al., May 2019\hfill\mbox{}}
    \node[align=left, draw=black,
                  xscale=1.0, yscale=1.0, 
                  rounded corners=1.5ex,
                  inner xsep=0.150cm,
                  above = 0.00cm of aa,
                  text width=0.5\textwidth,
                  font=\tiny
                  ] (reference) {\myreference};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I liked your answer since it met my objectives, but I found the answer that preserved the minipage to be more aligned with my goals.  Thanks!

Comment: @DavidCollins That's fine, of course. Note, however, that using `\tiny` as in the accepted answer is wrong. It has to be set with `font=\tiny`.